# How to read known_hosts file from "Resources" folder in a Spring Boot Application with Cloud Config Server and SSH enabled

Tags: java, spring, ssh, config, hosts

I have a spring boot application which has Config Server enabled with @EnableConfigServer annotation.
The config server connects to a Git repository hosted on Bitbucket.org using SSH Access key.
Since the spring boot app is intended to be deployed to Amazon Web Services, I want to have my 'hosts' file for SSH included in the project. Spring has a property for this:

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.known-hosts-file
```

The problem I am facing is the following: [KnownHostsFileValidator](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/blob/master/spring-cloud-config-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/config/server/ssh/KnownHostsFileValidator.java) (a class from spring config) tries to verify if the file exists with the following code:

```java
new File(knownHostsFile).exists()
```

If I want to include my hosts file in the resources directory to be packaged in the jar, then this validation fails, since the file name I give for the known-hosts-file property is not pointing to the "resources" directory.

My question is: how should the property for known-hosts-file look like to actually point to a file in the resources directory when "new File(filePath)" is executed?